# Woocommerce - way to give price to attribute?

Tags: php, wordpress, function, woocommerce, themes

So I am making a large Woocommerce shop for a customer, now they sell motorcycles and people can change all kinds of aspects about their vehicle (color, seats, saddle bags (optional), etc.).

Now creating variations from all these attributes (180 variations) is alot of work if I have to price each and every single variation (yes I know I can set a price for every variable at once), but isn't there a way for shopkeepers to give a price to their attributes so that when a variation is created with a certain attribute the product takes the standard price and adds the attribute prices?

Comment: This is just not possible… What you can do is set a variable product completely with all variations and prices. Then you make a duplicate of it and you just change what you need for that dup.

Comment: Yeah I had that solution as my backup, too bad there isn't a way to mass-select variations (not all) and change them. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

There is no native way of settings an price on attributes. The only way to do so is installing an extra addon: https://wordpress.org/plugins/markup-by-attribute-for-woocommerce/

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more details on what the package does and how it can be implemented.